# How Do I globally apply CSS in eclipse

Tags: css, javafx

I have made one CSS file for all fxml I have but I have no idea how to apply it to them.

[image]

I'm trying to apply `bakery.css` to all fxml file you see in the picture.
I have tried to put in the build path of the project but didn't work.
Is there a way to globally apply one CSS to all fxml files?

Comment: One option would be to write your own class that wraps up the `FXMLLoader`, and automatically applies the CSS before returning the loaded UI. Or if everything goes through your `SceneChanger` class, just do the same thing there. (I suppose this wouldn't work if you used `<fx:include ...>` though.)

Comment: You can take advantage of the fact style sheets are inherited from parents and/or the scene—see https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#introstylesheets.